# How to achieve zero downtime deployment to Azure web app with database updates?

Tags: database, azure, deployment

I'm trying to achieve **zero downtime deployments** of an Azure web app where **database schema updates** need to be applied as part of the deployment.

I have the following setup:

**Production** web app with **production-db** connection string.

**Staging** deployment slot with **staging-db** connection string.

My pseudo-deployment process is something like:

1. Make a copy of the **production-db** database
2. Configure the **Staging** slot to use the **database copy**
3. Deploy code to the **Staging** slot
4. Apply **schema updates** to the database copy
5. Test-run the app in the **Staging** slot (with the updated database) and pre-warm it
6. If everything works, perform a **hot swap** so that the pre-warmed app in the **Staging** slot goes live, i.e. becomes the production slot, **still using the updated database**

In other words, after the hot swap, I want both the new code and the updated database to be live.

If something goes wrong at this point, I can simply swap slots again, making the old production app (and its database) go live.

As I understand it now, when I swap slots, the app will use the connection string of the production slot, restarting the app and forcing me to apply the database schema updates *after* the updated code goes live.

I hope I'm describing this properly. :) This seems like it should be a fairly common scenario?

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated!

**PS.** I've looked at [Azure seamless upgrade when database schema changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597933/azure-seamless-upgrade-when-database-schema-changes), but that answer isn't valid, as I can't apply the schema updates without affecting the application.

**Edit:** Just a thought: perhaps I should skip putting the connection string as a portal setting, and instead just keep it in web.config. That way, when swapping, the app won't need to restart, and since web.config will be included in the swap, the new **production** slot will use the updated database.

**Edit 2:** I think I was mistaken about the app restart when app settings or connection strings differ between slots. It seems I can indeed set a different connection string (pointing to the database copy) for the deployment slot, and then swap without an app restart affecting website visitors.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find a valid solution for this?

Comment: @d.rodriguez Here's how we do it for Episerver websites: https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2017/zero-downtime-deployment-of-episerver/

Answer (score 0):

Could you not make the connection string sticky to the slot?

[image]

Full details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#configuration-for-deployment-slots).

Comment: Not really. :/ When swapping, the app would restart and point to the original production database, not the one upgraded through the deployment slot.